# PeerJs peer.connections deprecated

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, peerjs

I am trying to get all peers that are currently connected to me, but it says **connections** is deprecated.

```
const peer = new Peer('my_id');
const connections = peer.connections;
```

Documentation says: **We recommend keeping track of connections yourself rather than relying on this hash.**

Let's say I keep track of all peers id in array. How should I handle the ids so that I get the same result as with **peer.connections** ?

Example:
peer.connections returns: [image: peer.connections console.log]

What method do I need to call to get the same results from peer id in my array?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a listener when a connection is established. You may achieve this by implementing a wrapper that will unify client usage of `peer js`

```
class MyPeer {
  constructor() {
    this.instance = new Peer()
  }

  async connect() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.connection = peer.connect(new Date().getTime()) // create a unique id for each connection

      this.connection.on('open', () => resolve(this.connection))
    })
  }
}
```

Assuming you are taking this (very naïve, without proper error handling) implementation, you may keep track of connections like this

```
const peer = new MyPeer()
   
const connection = await peer.connect()
myConnectionsArray.push(connection)
```

It worth mentioning that you may remove connections from array when a connection is closed and probably wrap everything in a class (say `ConnectionsManagaer` or something similar). Besides that, it should satisfy your request